# equals method and single quote

Tags: android, equals

I've this code:

```
gProvincia = "Reggio nell'Emilia";
if (gProvincia.equals(provincia.getProperty("provincia").toString()))
{
    indiceSpinProv = x;
}
```

It seems that the single quote cause a problem to equals method, because setting `gProvincia` as `Parma`, equals return `true` when finds the same object in `provincia.getProperty("provincia")`. 
But this doesn't happen when the `gProvince` value contains a single quote.

I've also tried escaping the single quote with `"\"`, without success.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to treat a single quote in a string specially in Java. Something else is giving you the problem. Check if the value of the "provincia" property is correct.

Comment: `But this doesn't happen when the gProvince value contains a single quote.` there is no need to escape `'` in string ... in other words `provincia.getProperty("provincia")` is not equals  `gProvincia` ... end of story(remeber that whitspaces are important, too)